# functions with several variables: show injectivity

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $a,b \in \mathbb R,~ 0 < a < b$. Let $f=(f_1,f_2,f_3): \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ be defined by:

$f_1(s,t) = (b+a \cdot cos(s))cos(t)\\f_2(s,t)=(b+a \cdot cos(s))sin(t)\\f_3(s,t)=a \cdot sin(s)$

Let $K$ be the image of $f$.

I want to show that $g(t)=f(t,\lambda t)$ is an injective function of $\mathbb R$ on a dense subset of $K$, $\lambda \in \mathbb R, \notin \mathbb Q$ with $|g'(t)|^2 = a^2 + \lambda^2(b+ a \cdot cos(t))^2$. I don't really have an idea how to do that and would be pleased about help.

Thanks in advance!